# W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found

Tags: android, android-studio

When I launch app it the following error message appears in the LogCat:
W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
Device is Huawei p7  os4.4.2

How to solve or avoid this error?

Comment: It often happens on Chinese phones. Those miss the library

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this

Comment: Or what process is calling this library?